# Wordpress image name same as page

Tags: wordpress

Friends, i'm stuccoed with images in wordpress - please, help me understand where search for solution.

If you create webpage - www.wordpress.local/page1/01-0001 and you upload an image 01-0001 on that page, you can see, that when you'll visit www.wordpress.local/page1/01-0001, you'll see the page with image, not the page, that you created with text and images.

Any ideas how to solve it ?

PS Not renaming images :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the WordPress-uploader, the images are stored in */wp-content/uploads/*, and WordPress takes care of using filenames that aren't already in use.

If you upload an image, e.g. via FTP, that has the same name as a WordPress-page, the server has to decide what it should serve; either the WordPress-page or the image. One URL = one file served.

In your case, the server decides for the image. You could of course change this configuration; but in all cases, one of the two files won't be accessible.

If you want to make both files accessible, you either need to rename the image or the WordPress-page.

Comment: Friend, can you show me where i can change this configuration ?

Comment: WordPress generates an `.htaccess`-file in the WordPress-root containing RewriteRules. You'd need to change something in there. Maybe I can help you, if you post the contents of this file to http://www.pastie.org, *Friend.*